# Rewrite Rule(s) for domain aliases

Tags: mod-rewrite

Situation: I have a single (main) domain, which has several aliased domains, each of which are pointing at the same Plesk-based server (for instance, I have `example.com` as main, with `something.net`, `anotherone.co.uk`, and several others all as aliases of the main domain account). This means that whenever I enter the domain name into my address bar of any of the aliases, it goes directly to the account of the main domain (`example.com`).

**Problem:** Based on the domain name of the alias(es), I have an `index.php` that redirects each domain differently (for instance, requests to domain A redirects to a corporate site, domain b goes to a thanks site etc.) Which works great, but if a directory is added after the domain URL (i.e. `somealias.com/something`) then it gives a `404 not found` error.

What I would really appreciate, if someone can help me out, is a (single if possible) rewrite ruleset that would essentially strip off ALL trailing directories and/or GET requests, and only leave the typed-in base URL, so then the php script sitting in the main domain document root can take over and deal with the request appropriately.

Strangely enough, I've not been able to find a (simple) solution for this anywhere. Is it a case of having to define a rule for each of the aliased domains individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/? [L]
```

This will take **ALL** requests except root folder `/` (e.g. `http://example.com/`) or index file (e.g. `http://example.com/index.php`) and redirect them to the root folder (e.g. `http://example.com/some-url` will be redirected to `http://example.com/`).

You may need to replace `index.php` by the file that is get executed when you hit the root folder (Apache will silently rewrite  `http://example.com/` to `http://example.com/index.php` (depending on your actual settings) as it needs to have a file to execute otherwise it may show an error).

---

Alternatively (possibly even better -- depends on your actual setup and requirements) you may use these rules -- this will **redirect only non-existing URLs**. So if you have an image `meow.png` on your site, these rules will allow you to access it (`http://example.com/meow.png`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/? [L]
```

---

**UPDATE:**
If you going to place this into config file (httpd-vhost.conf or httpd.conf) then use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/? [L]
```

Comment: Hi; many thanks for your answer! I tried both options; unfortunately, since these rules have to go into the main domain top level vhost config file (like a root level htaccess), I can't use RewriteBase (which can only be used as a Directory directive). Both examples, although close, send the browser into an infinite loop, by appending index.php onto the end of the previous redirected URI string. It has, however, given me some more ammunition to play with - thanks again!

Comment: 1) You have tagged your question with `.htaccess` tag -- why did you used it if you have no intention to place rules in .htaccess? 2) Yes, RewriteBase cannot be used in config file -- only Directory or .htaccess 3) Yes, you will need to modify these rules a bit if you placing them in config file.

Comment: @User829303 Updated my answer with rules that can be placed in **httpd.conf** or other config file.

Comment: Many thanks... my apologies for the tag; my only excuse is that it's my first question, and still need to get to know the site. I've removed the irrelevant tag. I've tried the update, and unfortunately it still goes into an infinite redirect loop (on a URI of _example.com/testing_ Chrome reports it trying to get to _example.com/testing/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/..._ ad infinitum).

Comment: @user829303 I definitely tested it before posting -- you definitely have something else -- please update your question and show ALL rewrite rules you currently have -- there is no way that my updated version will produce `example.com/testing/index.php` as rule will **remove** `testing` part. Try another browser or clean caches -- the redirect most likely was cached by browser from previous attempts.

Comment: I have no other rewrite conditions or rules whatsoever for that domain. I only have a httpd.include file that has virtual host directives, none of which are mod_rewrite related. I applied your ruleset to the vhost.conf file, and got a colleague to try it on a "clean" browser; same thing, he got an infinite redirect error when trying to access example.com/whatever, appending index.php onto the /whatever/ directory. I really do appreciate your time to help me; very many thanks indeed, but it looks as though it's a deeper issue than just mod_rewrite.

Comment: @user829303 Maybe you do have rewrite rules somewhere in .htaccess? ... or maybe you do have `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` directives maybe?

Comment: Maybe you actually do have `testing` folder or alias? The rule will ignore existing folders. But then ... /testing/index.php/index.php -- not with this rules as the rule explicitly dropping everything when redirecting -- it redirects to a root folder.

Comment: just completed a full check of the system; the only items in the httpd config file are the servername and serveralias settings, virtual host directives (only containing php_admin settings - no mention of anything mod_rewrite related). Additionally, the domain document root has no .htaccess file, and no testing folders anywhere. The index.php within that document root effectively redirects requests based upon the URL server name to other (corporate) URIs, and nothing else. Still looking at the possibility that perhaps something went wrong with the original httpd build. Thanks again.

Comment: @user829303 In this case (+ the fact that you can edit server config) I would only suggest to enable rewrite debugging and see what is going on: [RewriteLogLevel 9](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel) and [RewriteLog /path/to/log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog)

Comment: Thanks; I'll try that when I'm next in the office - for now, I'm going home! I'm very grateful to you for your time and your assistance - many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following,

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$[OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; however, physically setting a rule for every aliased domain is something I want to try to avoid (I have something like 15 aliases at the moment, with more likely to be added). What I'd like is to somehow define a ruleset so it picks up whatever base URL (server name) has been typed into the address bar (for instance, if the request is **example.co.uk/somedir** I want it to go to **example.com** - similarly if the server name typed in is **anotheralias.com/anotherdir** I want it dynamically to go to **anotheralias.com**). Hope that clarifies the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that all the sites are hosted on the same server (probably using the same code base). 
If your index.php is a front controller you can redirect everything to your index.php and decide in the first lines of index.php what front controller to load (like backend.php).
If you don't mind having to maintain a list of the aliases you can define a hash of [alias] => path-to-front-controller.
In the front controller of you main domain you check the alias name (using $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] for example) against the hash and load the appropriate file.
You will have to add and entry to the hash each time you add anew alias. If they are not generated dynamically maintaining this hash is not a lot of hassle.